# where does lsusb -t get its data from?

Tags: command-line, lsusb

I want to the file from which the command

```
lsusb -t
```

retrieves the data. I am curious to see where this is stored.

[image: this is the snap]

and can anyone also tell that what can do with device id that displays in `fdisk -l`?

Comment: I have answered the `lsusb` related question..please ask a different question for `fdisk`

Answer (score 4):

`lsusb` reads its data from the kernel provided virtual `sys` Filesystem mounted in `/sys`;  specifically from the location of relevant directories for USB devices. These devices are connected to different PCI buses and are (mostly) detected by `udevd`.

For example, in my computer here is one example of the localtion of a USB device connected to a particular PCI bus:

```
/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb4/4-1/
```

The contents of the directory:

```
% print -l *
4-1:1.0
authorized
avoid_reset_quirk
bcdDevice
bConfigurationValue
bDeviceClass
bDeviceProtocol
bDeviceSubClass
bmAttributes
bMaxPacketSize0
bMaxPower
bNumConfigurations
bNumInterfaces
busnum
configuration
descriptors
dev
devnum
devpath
driver
ep_00
idProduct
idVendor
ltm_capable
maxchild
port
power
quirks
removable
remove
speed
subsystem
uevent
urbnum
version
```

`lsusb` just reads from relevant file(s) of this directory.

Answer (score 2):

`lsusb` uses **libudev** to fetch the list of devices you see. Libudev, in turn, uses a combination of the udev database and searching through the `/sys` filesystem to find hardware info.

Relevant code repositories:

https://github.com/gregkh/lsusb

http://cgit.freedesktop.org/systemd/systemd/tree/src/libudev

Answer (score 1):

Excuse me, I won't help you! If you want some fun:

```
ldd `which lsusb`
strace lsusb -t
ltrace -l "libudev*" lsusb -t
```

Well, I would suggest to read at least the long description (if not the whole manual) of each command using `man` or `info`.

Answer (score 0):

Kernel has drivers for the devices and kernel adds them. Devices report their capabilties to the driver or to the BIOS. Some of them are reported by BIOS. I know that because I had a BIOS with bug and it was reporting fans, which were not present. When processor got hot, the kernel driver tried to switch on inexistent fans. Finally I solved the problem by compiling the kernel without support for fans.

Take a look at `/sys/devices`. You will find your devices there. You can find lots of information about the devices in directories and files. Kernel creates them dynamically when devices are dis/connected.

Answer (score 0):

After a quick strace, I found that lsusb keeps a list of VID/PIDs that relate to product names in /var/lib/usbutils/usb.ids